# Why are my Outlook sent emails "disappearing" from the Sent messages folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I'm using Outlook 2007 with IMAP.  I've configured sent messages to be put in the server-based "Sent" folder of my IMAP account.  When I send emails, the email will briefly appear in the Sent messages folder and then disappear.  They might appear for just a few seconds up to an hour or so.  By "disappear" I mean that the messages are no longer in the list, and doing a search across all folders (I created a Search Folder to search for all messages) the message does not come up at all.  I had a number of rules but I disabled them all and the problem still occurs.  In addition I disabled AutoArchiving and ensured that there were no filters on the Sent folder.

Comment: Have you checked archives? You might have Outlook set to Archive on some crazy fast schedule.

Comment: @MrStatic - I did.  My archive file wasn't open so I opened it and browsed it, as well as made a search folder in there with no results.

Comment: Is there a web interface for your imap connection that you may be able to check?  Is it possible that  rule setup by the imap hosts have started causing this behavior?

Comment: @francisswest - There is.  I checked that too - I searched all folders and I don't see the emails.  What do you mean rule setup by the imap hosts?

Comment: Outlook has a setting to "keep replies with original message" if your original message was in a sub-folder (not Inbox). Moreover, this might be your IMAP server playing tricks, and not an Outlook problem at all...

Comment: Is the sent folder mapped to the correct folder on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Hi

I've not got enough magic internet points to add this as a comment but I had the same problem. even after checking all troubleshooting stuff mentioned here and elsewhere.

My solution was to delete the following:
OutlPrnt
Outcmd.dat
Outlook.srs
Outlook.xml
(my mail profile is called outlook)
and I left the Outlook.NK2 file in tact then rebooted and it worked.

Back up these files before deleting just in-case it breaks anything.

Answer (score 1):

FOUND:  I experienced just within the last few days certain "sent" emails that were no where to be found ... at least, not in the conventional Outlook folders. I found them in my icloud sent folder. Don't know why they appeared there, and I don't use the name@icloud.com email function, but now I know where they are and will resolve the issue from there (probably deleting the iClould email account.